# Decorate commands with bash function

Tags: bash

I would like to decorate some commands (`conda` and `mamba` in my case), but ***not** all commands* (so not as described in [this Stack Exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369540/catch-and-decorate-each-command-before-execution)).

Thanks to [this Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125853/457538), I managed to do it for the `conda` command, but not for the `mamba` one, by putting the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
decorate () {
    # From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125853/457538
    eval "_inner_$(typeset -f $1)"
    eval "
        $1 () {

            echo "BEFORE"
            _inner_$1 \$@
            local ret=\$?
            echo "AFTER"
            return \$ret
        }
    "
}

decorate conda
decorate mamba
```

It does work for `conda` and not for `mamba` since this implementation relies on `typeset -f $1` to recopy the decorated function with a new name (`_inner_$1`) and override the original one, and that this (`typeset -f $1`) only works for actual bash functions (`conda` is one), and not for binaries (as `mamba` is).

For `mamba`, `typeset -f $1` returns nothing, hence when I `source ~/.bashrc` I get the following error from the line `eval "_inner_$(typeset -f $1)"`

```
_inner_: command not found
```

And when I try to use the decorated `mamba` I get:

```
~$ mamba
BEFORE
_inner_mamba: command not found
AFTER
```

So, I can't find a way to decorate a binary command via a bash function, and I'm interested in a general solution for this problem.

However, if that matters, my real goal for now is to temporarily modify the `umask` during `conda` or `mamba` execution, then, if there is an alternative way for this specific case, I'll take that too.

Comment: `to decorate a binary command via a bash function` So just call the binary?

Comment: Yes, but with some work before and after. Your answer works fine, I accepted it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two paths - one for function one for command. Remember about quoting arguments - always quote variable expansions. Remember about quotes - your use of `"` quotes is strange, be consistent. Simplified proof of concept:

```
decorate () {
    if [[ -n "$(typeset -f "$1")" ]]; then
        # From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125853/457538
        eval "_inner_$(typeset -f $1)"
        eval "
            $1 () {
        
                echo \"BEFORE\"
                _inner_$1 \"\$@\"
                local ret=\$?
                echo \"AFTER\"
                return \$ret
            }
        "
    else
        eval "
            $1 () {
        
                echo \"BEFORE\"
                command $1 \"\$@\"
                local ret=\$?
                echo \"AFTER\"
                return \$ret
            }
        "
    fi
}
```

Note that your command is very unsafe - `decorate 'rm -r / ; func'` will execute inside `eval` and remove all your files. Make sure to protect against such mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! This do work for `conda` and `mamba` now, I forget about the `command` command. It does not work for `ls` though, but nevermind I'll not use that. And, yes, I still have trouble with nested variables expansions and quoting, thanks.